# Set Custom Font To Spinner

Tags: android, xamarin.android

This has been asked a lot, however it hasnt been asked for xamarin.

This is my problem:

I have a layout file for my custom spinner:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/xy1z"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp" />
```

And I have a custom spinner:

```
        spnMyFriends = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.txt_myfriends_addafriend);

        String[] friends = new String[]
        {
            "My friends",
            "I am following",
        };



        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, Resource.Layout.spinner_item, friends);

        spinnerArrayAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Resource.Layout.spinner_item);
        spnMyFriends.Adapter = spinnerArrayAdapter;

        spnMyFriends.ItemSelected += new EventHandler
            <AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(SpinnerItems);
```

Now, you would think that since I can edit the xml file, I can simply do this:

```
Textview txtv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.xy1z);
txtv.SetTypeFace(font, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
```

This works for EVERY SINGLE textview - it however doesnt work for my spinner.
The last line, where I set the font crashes with "... not set instance of an object".
What ofcourse is wrong, since I initialized the Textview object in the line before that... So,

1.) Why is my idea not working?
2.) How do I get to change the font?

Help would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why

The `Spinner` is adapter pattern. You are in the wrong place to set the typeface.

> This works for EVERY SINGLE textview.

Yes, you can find a `TextView` in your Activity's layout and configure its typeface, because Activity need the layout to show it content.

The `Spinner` also have a layout as you can see it is a popup, its content need `Adapter` to configure, so in the `Adapter` you can get the `TextView` and set its typeface.

### How

Like @elmorabea has said, you need a custom `Adapter` and in the `GetView` method, you need to set the `Typeface`,  below is a simple:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Spinner spnMyFriends;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        initView();
    }

    private void initView()
    {
        spnMyFriends = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.txt_myfriends_addafriend);

        List<string> friends = new List<string>
        {
        "My friends",
        "I am following",
        };
        
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this,friends);
        spnMyFriends.Adapter = myAdapter;

    }
    
}

public class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
{
    Context mContext;
    readonly LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<string> itemList;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<string> list) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.FromContext(context);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.itemList = list;
    }
    public override string this[int position]
    {
        get { return itemList[position]; }
    }
    public override int Count {
        get { return itemList.Count; }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView ?? inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.spinner_item, parent, false);

        var item = itemList[position];

        TextView tv = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.xy1z);
        // here to set your Typeface
        Typeface typeFace1 = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(mContext.Assets, "fonts/NotoSansCJK-Black.ttc");
        tv.SetTypeface(typeFace1, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
        tv.Text = itemList[position];
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Insane work! This couldnt work ANY better. Thanks, my friend!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is where you are `find`ing your view.

You are calling `findViewById()` on your `activity`, which doesn't not have the `dropDown` view of the `spinner`.

`Spinners` create a popup and show the list on it, that is not part of your activity's view, it's sort of floating above it.

What you need is a custom `Adapter`, where you override `getView()` and return a properly configured view with a fancy custom TypeFace.